# How to create average heat maps

Tags: heatmap

I have six sample which are not similar in row and columns and I need to produce average heat map of those samples. Can you please tell me how can I make average of them as some sample have three row and some of them fur or five. So due to difference value when I will do average the in cage so low rows or columns how can I average it? Can anyone help me with this issue?

I produce bins of different samples now want to produce average data to produce average heat maps. I face problem in doing that one....

Comment: Typo alert: it's **average** -not "avarage"